# Python3 Import Error with pycurl Mac OS X

Tags: python, homebrew

I have installed `pycurl` via `pip` on OS X 10.9. When I run python file with `import pycurl` python tells me next error:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pycurl.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _PyFile_AsFile   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pycurl.so
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pycurl.so

UPD: `python3` installed via `brew`

Comment: It's important to mention you are using homebrew.

Comment: @SethMMorton, I used pip3 when I installed pycurl. It's installed without any errors.